# Haskell basic classes

Tags: haskell

Rookie question, why this is not correct in Haskell?

```
class BasicEq a where
    isEqual :: a -> a -> Bool
    isNotEqual :: a -> a -> Bool
    isNotEqual = not . isEqual
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's open up the GHC prompt and look at the types of things:

```
Prelude> :t not
not :: Bool -> Bool
Prelude> :t (not .)
(not .) :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> Bool
```

So you can see `(not .)` takes a `a -> Bool`, not an `a -> a -> Bool`.  We can double up the function composition to get a working version:

```
Prelude> :t ((not .) .)
((not .) .) :: (a -> a1 -> Bool) -> a -> a1 -> Bool
```

So the correct definition is:

```
isNotEqual = (not .) . isEqual
```

Or equivalently,

```
isNotEqual x y = not $ isEqual x y
isNotEqual = curry $ not . uncurry isEqual
```

et cetera.

Answer (score 6):

The `.` operator expects two "unary functions" ("x -> y"), but `isEqual` is a "binary function" ("x -> y -> z"), so it won't work. You could just don't use the point-free form:

```
isNotEqual x y = not $ isEqual x y
```